# Check if times overlap using moment?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have an array of `[start_time, end_time]` time ranges like so:

```
let timeSegments = [];
timeSegments.push(["02:00", "07:00"])
timeSegments.push(["03:00", "04:00"])
```

These time segments overlap, since `2AM - 7AM` includes `3AM - 4AM`

Likewise:

```
let timeSegments = [];
timeSegments.push(["14:00", "18:00"])
timeSegments.push(["15:00", "19:00"])
```

`2PM` to `6PM` overlaps with `3PM` to `7PM`.

I'm using the momentjs library, and would like to know a way to determine if my timeSegments array contains any timeSegments that overlap? The timeSegments array can contain at most 10 `[start_time, end_time]` pairs. Thanks!

I'd just like to know if any segments overlap (true/false), I don't need to know which of the segments overlap etc.

Comment: So what do you want the result to be? `true` if *any* times in your array overlap? The overlapping times? The *number* of overlaps? Is your array always ordered as per your example (earliest->latest)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can sort `timeSegments` by `start_time` (using [`Array.prototype.sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)) and iterate through the sorted list and check if `end_time` of the current timeSegment is greater than `start_time` of the next one.

If that happens, there is an overlap.

You can see an example of implementation below:

```js
const checkOverlap = (timeSegments) => {
  if (timeSegments.length === 1) return false;

  timeSegments.sort((timeSegment1, timeSegment2) =>
    timeSegment1[0].localeCompare(timeSegment2[0])
  );

  for (let i = 0; i < timeSegments.length - 1; i++) {
    const currentEndTime = timeSegments[i][1];
    const nextStartTime = timeSegments[i + 1][0];

    if (currentEndTime > nextStartTime) {
      return true;
    }
  }

  return false;
};

const timeSegments1 = [
  ["03:00", "04:00"],
  ["02:00", "07:00"],
  ["12:00", "15:00"]
];

const timeSegments2 = [
  ["05:00", "07:00"],
  ["03:00", "04:00"],
  ["12:00", "15:00"]
];

console.log(checkOverlap(timeSegments1)); // prints true
console.log(checkOverlap(timeSegments2)); // prints false
```

Note that `Array.prototype.sort` mutates the array, performing the sort in-place. If you want to preserve the array passed to `checkOverlap` (which is, in general, a good practice), you can create a copy of `timeSegments` (using the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax), for example):

```
const sortedTimeSegments = [...timeSegments].sort(...);
```

Answer (score 17):

You can use [moment-range](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/plugins/range/) plugin. You can create a range using [`moment.range`](https://github.com/gf3/moment-range#create) function passing moment objects as input (parse your input strings using [`moment(String, String)`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/)). Then you can use the [`overlap`](https://github.com/gf3/moment-range#overlaps) method that checks if two ranges overlap.

Here a live sample:

```js
window['moment-range'].extendMoment(moment);

let overlap = (timeSegments) => {
  let ret = false;
  let i = 0;
  while( !ret && i<timeSegments.length-1 ){
    let seg1 = timeSegments[i];
    let seg2 = timeSegments[i+1];
    let range1 = moment.range( moment(seg1[0], 'HH:mm'),  moment(seg1[1], 'HH:mm'));
    let range2 = moment.range( moment(seg2[0], 'HH:mm'),  moment(seg2[1], 'HH:mm'));
    if( range1.overlaps(range2) ){
      ret = true;
    }
    i++;
    
    return ret;
  }
};

let timeSegments = [];
timeSegments.push(["02:00", "07:00"])
timeSegments.push(["03:00", "04:00"])
console.log( overlap(timeSegments) ); // true

timeSegments = [];
timeSegments.push(["14:00", "18:00"])
timeSegments.push(["15:00", "19:00"])
console.log( overlap(timeSegments) ); // true

timeSegments = [];
timeSegments.push(["14:00", "18:00"])
timeSegments.push(["19:00", "21:00"])
console.log( overlap(timeSegments) ); // false
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-range/3.0.3/moment-range.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: If you have time ranges that cross midnight, split the range into two ranges (e.g. 22:00-04:00 would create 22:00-24:00 and 00:00-04:00) and do the overlaps check with the two.

Answer (score 1):

you can take the reference form the following code. I am using core JavaScript for this.

```
<script>
    var obj = [{ "from": "08:00", "to": "9:01" }, { "from": "18:45", "to": "19:00" }, { "from": "08:00", "to": "09:00" }, { "from": "12:00", "to": "14:00" }];
    obj = sortTime(obj);
    console.log(obj);
    if (checkoverlapping(obj)) {
        alert("yes time overlaps");
    } else {
        alert("No overlapping")
    }

    function sortTime(obj) {
        obj.sort(function (a, b) {
            KeyA = minuteValue(a.from);
            KeyB = minuteValue(b.from);

            if (KeyA < KeyB) return -1;
            else if (KeyA > KeyB) return 1;
            else {
                a = minuteValue(a.to);
                b = minuteValue(b.to);
                if (a < b) return -1;
                if (a > b) return 1;
                return 0
            }
        })
        return obj;
    }

    function minuteValue(time) {
        time = time.split(":");
        return (time[0] * 60) + (time[1] * 1);
    }


    function checkoverlapping(obj) {
        let previous = obj[0], current, overlapping = false;
        for (let i = 1; i < obj.length; i++) {
            current = obj[i]
            if (minuteValue(previous.to) > minuteValue(current.from)) {
                overlapping = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        return overlapping;
    }

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `moment` to compare actual `dates` and check for overlaps between them:

```
function rangeOverlap(range1, range2, gran = "hour", inc = "[]") {

  const [ start1, end1 ] = range1;
  const [ start2, end2 ] = range2;

  // check range1 is between range2
  const startFirst = start1.isBetween(start2, end2, gran, inc)
  const endFirst = end1.isBetween(start2, end2, gran, inc)

  // check range2 is between range1
  const startLast = start2.isBetween(start1, end1, gran, inc)
  const endLast = end2.isBetween(start1, end1, gran, inc)

  return startFirst || endFirst || startLast || endLast
}
```

Then, consider this example:

```
const range1 = [
  moment("2022-02-22T10:00:00"), // start
  moment("2022-02-23T10:00:00")  // end
]

const range2 = [
  moment("2022-02-22T10:00:00"), // start
  moment("2022-02-23T10:00:00")  // end
]

const overlap = rangeOverlap(range1, range2)
console.log("Overlaps:", overlap)
```