# looking to see if 2 times overlap with moment.JS

Tags: javascript, object, time, momentjs

I am trying to see if two times, both with start and end times, overlap in any way. for instance, if A has a start time of 0800 and an end time of 0900 and I want to see if B, which has a start time of 0845 and an end time of 0945, interests/ overlaps it in any way. I don't care about the actual date just the times.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if times overlap using moment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44800471/check-if-times-overlap-using-moment)

Comment: @VincenzoC no they are different

Comment: What is the difference?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this specifically using moment.js then you can try this plugin `moment-range` which allows you to have two date ranges and a function `overlaps` that can check this for you.

https://github.com/rotaready/moment-range#overlaps

Alternatively, you can manually do this check with if statements as well if you don't want to use moment.js.

Comment: I did look at this and am using it but how do I create the ranges?  right now I have something that looks like this: `const range2 = moment.range(8, 9)` where 8 and 9 are 8AM and 9 is 9AM.

Comment: what is the way to do it with if statements?

Answer (score 0):

You want to check if the
EndDate of A > StartDate of B
EndDate of B > Start

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).