# Check if more than two time ranges overlap in angular

Tags: angular, time

[three time ranges](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h9asu.png)

In this case, i need to validate those three time ranges, and user will only be able to save them if they dont have overlap.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44800471/check-if-times-overlap-using-moment

Answer (score 1):

Well, the formula for two time ranges is well known: [Determine Whether Two Date Ranges Overlap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/325933/determine-whether-two-date-ranges-overlap)

So, you need to check that this check is verified for any pair, like this:

```js
function areOverlapping(a, b) {
  return (a.startA <= b.end) && (a.end >= b.start);
}

function anyOverlap(intervals: any[]) { 
  for(let i = 0; i < intervals.length - 1; i++) {
    for(let j = i + 1; j < intervals.length; j++) {
      if (areOverlapping(intervals[i], intervals[j])) return true;
    }
  }

  return false;
}

if (anyOverlap([interval1, interval2, interval3])) {
  // there is at least a pair that overlaps.
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. It looks really helpful. I am trying to implement it right now.